# Load a layer from a PostgreSQL using Graphical Modeler in QGIS after filtering with multiple input variables

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-modeler

I have a table in a PostgreSQL database. I want to pull in features from it as a layer that match the Date range and Lat/Long specified as an input while running a QGIS Graphical Modeler. Some other functions would then be performed on this layer within the model.

I tried to use the 'PostgreSQL execute and load SQL' algorithm within the model, but I can only input one variable at the end of a query by using the 'Pre-calculate Value' option.

How can this be undertaken?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?